# -bash: laravel: command not found - Mac High Siera

Tags: php, bash, macos, laravel, laravel-5

I've installed a fresh copy of High Sierra today (After resetting my whole mac) so now I am at the point of installing all things related to programming, like the Laravel installer for now.

I have problems with installing the laravel installer and with the path I suppose.
I know there are a lot of questions a bit similiar to this but for some reason I haven't found the right answer yet.

So as the documentation of Laravel said I installed composer and that works just fine. After that I installed the Laravel installer with composer. I placed the command(?) for my path in the .bashrc file but after a re open of my terminal the command Laravel was not found. I knew from previous times this thing was a pain in the ass and I am also not very familiar with all those things in the command line so this is kinda hard for me.

What I did:

1) I installed composer. After that, I did `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer` in my terminal. Also I did `mkdir -p /usr/local/bin` because i had a fresh install so those directories were not found of course, because they didn't exist.

2) After that I ran `composer global require "laravel/installer"` in my terminal. This was all going great.

3) Last step was to do this thing with the PATH. I still don't know if I did this right. What I did was `nano ~/.bashrc` and then added `export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH` to this file. This did not work, so I still can't use Laravel .. in my terminal. I don't know much about this `source` command but when I do `source ~/.bashrc` I can use this Laravel command but when I open a new tab or window I can't use it anymore.

4) Besides `export PATH=~/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH` in the .bashrc file I also tried `export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"` in that file. that doesn't work either.

Is there someone that can help me out? Good to know is that I just installed a fresh copy of OS and did nothing besides installing some normal programms. Laravel/Composer were my first things with the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that your terminal program is set to create a login shell, which doesn't source ~/.bashrc

Try adding this to ~/.bash_profile

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Great! Bit strange that it doesn't work out of the box but this is good enough I guess.